# Depends: daemon but it is not yet installable - Jenkins install on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install Jenkins on a Virtual machine running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS via the following guide (https://websiteforstudents.com/install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-lts-server/).

I am having issues when running the command:

```
sudo apt install jenkins
```

Which is giving the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  jenkins : Depends: daemon but it is not installable
```

I have tried running:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

But I am still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Ended up solving this by running the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```